# For which Banach spaces is the self composition operator Lipschitz?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X\subseteq \{f|f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n\}$ be a Banach space, with at least all polynomials on $D$ contained in $X$, where $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and bounded.

Let $U\subseteq X\cap \{f|f:D\rightarrow D\}$ be open, and define the operator $\Phi:U\rightarrow U$ by $\Phi(f)=f\circ f$ for all $f\in U$.

For which spaces $X$ and sets $D$ is $\Phi$ Lipschitz?

---

Note: $C^n_b(D,\mathbb{R}^n)$ does not work for any finite $n$, as for $\Phi$ to be Lipschitz, the $n$<sup>th</sup> derivative of $f$ needs to be Lipschitz, and the set of functions with Lipschitz $n$<sup>th</sup> derivative has empty interior in $C^n_b(D,\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Likewise the space of bounded Lipschitz functions does not work due to the requirement for $f\circ f-g\circ g$ to have Lipschitz modulus bounded by some multiple of $\|f-g\|$. (Consider e.g. $n=1$, $D=[-1,1]$, $f(x)=\max\{0,x\}-a$, $g(x)=\max\{0,x\}-b$, with $0<a<b<1$ then $f(x)-g(x)=b-a$, so $L(f-g)=0$ and $\|f-g\|_\infty\rightarrow 0$ as $b\rightarrow a$. But for $x\in (a,b)$, $f(f(x))=x-2a$ while $g(g(x))=-b$, so $L(f\circ f - g\circ g)=1$ no matter how close are $a$ and $b$.)

Comment: Both of your non-examples involve spaces where the norm measures something related to difference quotients; I suspect you might have more luck with norms which measure other things. What about having $X$ be a closed subspace of $C_b(D,\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: The Lipschitz functions with modulus less than some constant are such a closed subset, and $\Phi$ is Lipschitz on this subset. But a closed subset of a Banach space is not itself a Banach space, as it is not closed under the vector operations. I need an implicit function theorem, which as far as I know requires $X$ to be Banach, not just a closed subset of a Banach space. But maybe I'm misunderstanding you?

Comment: @DCM Tagging as I forgot to tag above.

Comment: I meant 'closed *linear* subspace'

Comment: @DCM Ahh OK sorry. Do you have a suggestion for which closed linear subspace might have this property? (Beyond just the linear functions.)

Comment: I think the problem here is more about norms than about spaces, as in 'once you have a norm which works, you can get lots of different spaces which do by taking completions of your favorite not-necessarily-closed linear subspaces of $C_b(D,\mathbb{R}^n)$'

Comment: $X = C_b(D,\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $X=C_b(\bar D, \mathbb{R}^n)$ are two 'boring' examples. The harmonic members (i.e. those which satisfy $\Delta f_i = 0$ for $i=1,...,n$) of these two spaces should also work (I think!), and might be a bit more interesting.

Comment: Re. *I need an implicit function theorem* (and just in case it helps) - there are also implicit function theorems for other types of topological vector spaces besides the Banach spaces (like the famous 'Nash-Moser' one)

Comment: Can you give any more background about what you want to do? e.g. why do you need $\Phi$ to be Lipschitz, how does the implicit function theorem fit in?

Comment: @DCM Why would $\Phi$ be Lipschitz on $C_b(D,\mathbb{R}^n)$ (by which I take it you mean the space of bounded continuous functions)? $\|f(f(x))-g(g(x))\|\le \|f(f(x))-f(g(x))\|+\|f(g(x))-g(g(x))\|$. Only if $f$ is Lipschitz is the former term less than $\|f-g\|$.

Comment: @DCM I know about the Nash Moser theorem. I was hoping to avoid it using it as it seems extremely "heavy weight", and the proof needs to be comprehensible for non-mathematicians. Plus, I'm not aware of versions of the Nash Moser theorem for set valued functions. At the moment I'm relying Theorem 5J.9 of Dontchev and Rochafellar's Implicit Functions book.

Comment: @DCM I'm trying to prove existence of solution of a certain functional equation, given existence in a certain special case. The implicit function theorem should get me there if only I can find the right space/norm!

Comment: Re. everything being ok for the uniform norm: you're right and I was wrong. I didn't think it through - sorry! (I'm used to my composition operators being of the form $\Phi: f\mapsto f\circ \phi$)

Comment: In "Let $X\subset\{f:D\to\mathbf{R}^n\}$ be a Banach space", is it supposed that the norm on $X$ is related to the ambient space?

Comment: @YCor Yes. Good point. The norm should be "natural".

Comment: @cfp Should I guess what "natural" means? Probably one wants the inclusion map to be continuous. Is this enough?

Comment: @YCor I guess so. I appreciate natural is a bit nebulous. Any of the standard spaces Lp, Sobolev, C meet the standard.

Comment: @YCor I've simplified the problem to just requiring polynomials to be in $X$, not $C^\infty(\overline{D},\mathbb{R}^n)$. Under this simplification, there is at least one satisfactory $X$, $\{F\in \mathcal{l}^\infty(\mathbb{N},C_b(D,\mathbb{R}^n))|\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, F_{n+1}=F_n'\}$. See e.g. the comments here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541101/a-strange-norm-in-the-polynomial-space-mathbbp0-1-a-contradiction .

Comment: Scrach that. I don't think the space in the previous comment contains an open set which is closed under self composition, as e.g. $\exp$ is in the space, but $\exp\exp$ is not.